# IE Javascript/jQuery Woes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I recently rebuilt a website for a friend of mine, adding a blog and porting his portfolio into Pods CMS (The site is built on Wordpress). What was a previously-working portfolio gallery/type thing is now completely broken in IE and I don't know why - it works fine in Firefox/Chrome/Safari and used to work fine in IE too until I changed some id/class names and updated the JS.

Here is the URL: http://www.notjones.com/work/

IE is throwing an error at me:

```
object required
work, line 53, character 3
```

which is the following:

```
<h1 id="logo"><a href="http://www.notjones.com/">NotJones</a></h1>
```

That doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Comment: Any reason that you need 2 different versions of jquery?

Comment: It won't be line 53 of your html page, it will be the js that's causing the error.

Comment: @redsquare. The Pods CMS plugin imports an older version, I'm going to look at that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the developer tools of ie8 you can find the line of code throwing the error:

```
function __flash__removeCallback(instance, name) {
  instance[name] = null; //error in ie
}
```

this piece of code is inserted by flash player when you're using ExternalInterface in the actionscript code of your swf. i'll try to find what's going wrong here

edit: the only swf instances you're using seems to be vimeo players:

```
<object height="360" width="552"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf...
```

try removing these. if the error's gone, you might just have to apply a valid 'id' attribute to the corresponding 'object' tags, as suggested [here](http://www.quantumtom.com/2010/04/20/fix-for-ie-choking-on-__flash__removecallback/)

Comment: Ah, clicking the error in the IE dev tool took me to the HTML. Will have a look at this, thanks!

Comment: In the end, I just used the new iframe embeds from Vimeo and this problem went away..

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove the error by adding both an id attribute to the object tag and a name attribute to the embed tag, like so:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="400" height="226" id="player_1234567890">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=1234567890&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00adef&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" />
<embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=1234567890&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00adef&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="400" height="226" name="player_1234567890" />
</object>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

One fun thing about working with IE: the error message doesn't tell you which file has the error; just the webpage where the file is included.

I don't have IE so I can't check, but line 53 on all your JS files, and make sure all the objects there are defined/exist.

Comment: Just one of many fun things when working with IE. Thanks Microsoft, we love you!